# Show that multiplicative order mod p exists and that it divides (p-1)

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $p$ be some odd prime.  Let $r$ be the smallest natural number such that $x^r \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for some $x \in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$.

Prove that such an $r$ exists, and that it divides $(p-1)$.

---

My thoughts: that it exists seems trivial.  The field is finite, so all elements must have some finite order?  Not sure how to state this rigorously though.  For $r \mid (p-1)$ I'm thinking Lagrange's theorem seems an obvious choice.  Guidance appreciated.

Comment: This : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem will help you.

Comment: $\mathbf F_p^\times$ is a multiplicative group and $r$ is the order of the subgroup generated by $x$.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the division theorem. Write $p-1 = qr + s$ where $q\in \mathbb Z$ and $0\le s <r$. We want to use the fact that $r$ is minimal to deduce that $s=0$, and hence that $r\mid p-1$.

By Fermat's little theorem, $x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. By assumption, $x^{r} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and hence $x^{qr} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, so $x^{p-1 - qr} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Can you finish from here?

---

Alternatively, you can work group theoretically: what is the order of the subgroup $\langle x\rangle \le \mathbb F_p^\times$? What can you deduce about its order?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you are asked to prove something that seems obvious, proofs by contradiction can really come in handy. Think about what it would mean if there were no smallest $r\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^r \equiv 1 modp$?

The second portion seems like something that might contradict a theorem of Fermat if it were not true ;). (Hint: it's not his big theorem).