# Solve $11^a \equiv 1 \mod 19$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Find all of the possible solutions for $11^a \equiv 1 \mod 19$ . I tried to add multiples of $19$ to $1$ but it didn't work . Also Fermat's little theorem wasn't helpful .

Comment: Of course Fermat's Little Theorem is directly helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fermat's little theorem, $11^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 19$, and so the answer must be all multiples of $d$ where $d$ is some divisor of $18$.  The divisors of $18$ are $1, 2, 3, 6, 9$.  Try $2$, then $3$ ...

Comment: You can narrow it down with $11\equiv (-2)^3\pmod{19}$ and $11\equiv 7^2\pmod{19}.$

Comment: If $3$ is the first answer why we have $a = 3k$ in general ?

Comment: It's easy to prove: if $m$ is the least positive integer such that $b^m \equiv 1 \mod n$, then $b^{km} \equiv 1 \mod n$ for all $k$, and if $b^c \equiv 1 \mod n$ for some $c$ not a multiple of $m$, then there is $k$ such that $0 < c-km < m$ and $b^{c-km} \equiv 1 \mod n$, contradicting the assumption that $m$ was the least...

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 3):

By FLT we know that a solution is $a=18$ then we need also to try with $a=2,3,6,9$ and by inspection we find that $a=3$ is a solution, we say that $ord_{19}(11)=3$, and thus all $a=3k$ are solutions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with $ord$ notation . Can you explain it ?

Comment: When we find $a = 18$ , why we should try divisors of $18$ ?

Comment: The multiplicative order divides $\mod p$ divides $p-1$, take a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1497484/505767